# Rename all tables in database

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

I have a database where all of the tables are prefixed with a set of the same characters. This was done because at one time they were in a shared database set up for pet projects with hundreds of other tables. The application, and thus the database, is now ready to be moved out of that phase and ready to be out on it's own. I would like to remove the prefix for each of the tables. Is there an easier way to do this rather than right-clicking and renaming each table individually?

Comment: I would've created a new database, with the new naming scheme for new tables, and selected the data across.

Comment: Take a look at this too - "Mass Renaming of Tables and Stored Procedures" http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1098585/mass-renaming-of-tables-and-stored-procedures

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do something like script the whole database and do string replacement on the script, run it on a new database, and then import the data.  This of course depends on how well you can match the string to be replaced.  You might have to make corresponding changes in your application too.  You could always try something like this on a test database to see if it would work.

Take a look at this too - [Mass Renaming of Tables and Stored Procedures](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1098585/mass-renaming-of-tables-and-stored-procedures)

One method has some cost and the other is similar to my suggestion.

Comment: @Bratch +1 a much nicer way of saying what I said.

Comment: @Hogan Yeah, but different.  Your answer sounds more like actually writing a script to modify the meta data.  I'm not saying you need to write a script at all, just script out the database as SQL commands (Right-click, Tasks, Generate Scripts).  Do a find/replace and replace the prefix with nothing, and then run the modified SQL on the new database.  This will rename all references to the tables in the views and sprocs too.  A quick look at the SQL generated by the db script should give an idea if it will work right or not.

Answer (score 12):

```
select 'exec sp_rename @objname=' + name + ', @newname=' + replace(name ,'prefixedchars', '')
from sysObjects
where type = 'U'
```

The results from this will be something like:

```
exec sp_rename @objname=prefixedcharsTable1, @newname=Table1
exec sp_rename @objname=prefixedcharsTable2, @newname=Table2
exec sp_rename @objname=prefixedcharsTable3, @newname=Table3
etc... for each table in your db
```

All you have to do is copy those statements into a new query window and run.

Caveats:

- You will get an cautionary message as follows: `Caution: Changing any part of an object name could break scripts and stored procedures.`
- You will have to rename the tables in any stored procedures, functions, views, and triggers.

Comment: This is a great solution because you can see the rename script before it runs.

Answer (score 4):

You could write a script to look at the meta information and change it, but won't this ruin all your SPs and Parameterized Queries?

Comment: It'll ruin everything - views, etc.  If there's SCHEMABINDING on anything, that'll have to be dealt with first...

Answer (score 0):

First, write a stored procedure that has a table name parameter and uses string parsing and ALTER TABLE to remove the prefix from the specified table.

Then, use sp_MSforeachtable to call that procedure for each table.

Reference: http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/joew/archive/2007/10/23/60383.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Purely from the "replacement for right-click, rename" perspective (not renaming references, procedures, views, etc) - mix it up a little.  Get the list of tables:

```
select name from sys.Tables
```

copy and past it into emacs (or your favourite regex line editor) and run a regex line replacement:
search`\(xyz.*\)` and replace with `SP_RENAME 'xyz\1', '\1';`
This repalces the table xyzFoo with Foo.  Paste the lines back into SQL Server and run it.