# SQL script to rename all the table names with new name if it containes required string in mySQL and MsSQL

Tags: mysql, sql-server-2005

I have one database with 100 tables in it. out of 100 some tables have name like `House, House1, House2 , HouseXYZ` and so on.

Now I want to write a script in MySQL and MsSQL to replace the `House` with `Home`. So my database should be having the table name `Home, Home1, Home2, HomeXYZ` and so on.

Comment: You sure you want to do that? Any existing objects which reference any tables will lose the reference. i.e you'd have to edit every function, procedure, trigger...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Rename all tables in database](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2008412/rename-all-tables-in-database)

Comment: yes, I have to do it. I have to do same with columns too.

Comment: Actually I am not sure how to handle this case. I mean how to do pattern matching and replace House with Home and rest of the string in table name  should remain same.

Comment: did one of the solutions below work for you

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2008412/rename-all-tables-in-database) you would you would do this for your table names:

```
select 'exec sp_rename @objname=' + name + ', @newname=' + replace(name ,'House', 'Home')
from sysObjects
where type = 'U'
```

Answer (score 1):

--MSSQL

```
SELECT 'exec sp_rename @objname=' + NAME + ', @newname=' + replace(NAME, 'House', 'Home')
FROM sysObjects
WHERE type = 'U'
    AND NAME LIKE 'House%'
```

--MYSQL

```
SELECT CONCAT (
        'ALTER TABLE '
        ,table_name
        ,' RENAME '
        ,replace(table_name, 'House', 'Home')
        )
FROM information_schema.tables
WHERE table_name LIKE 'House%'
```